# How to get original, not translated, name of the place using Google Places API?

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get info about some place, let's say I use this link `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJFfz5V9zi20ARwBqCYQXOIVM&fields=vicinity,name&key=MY_API_KEY`, I will get this result

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "Try Bobry",
      "vicinity" : "Dmytra Yavornytskoho Avenue, 42, Dnipro"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

but the original name of this place is `Три бобри`, not `Try Bobry`.

You say I can use `language=uk` parameter to get this name, but if I will use it - it will break another place, which original name is in English, for example this `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJHZkI69zi20ARfbLn6MV6S9o&fields=vicinity,name&key=MY_API_KEY&language=uk` will return

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "Візьміть каву, щоб піти",
      "vicinity" : "вулиця Барикадна, 5-7, Дніпро́"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

so it will be `Візьміть каву, щоб піти` instead of `Take coffee to go`.

All I want is to get places' names in the language of origin, not translated.